# How can we change View Visibility based on condition in flutter?

Tags: flutter

#**Show Views Visibility**
Actually I have an array where 6  items are in that array. In each item there is different status coming based on condition from api. I have to change status in row .Now in flutter how to hide and visible status as per condition in list in flutter.

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have?

Comment: After the api response comes you have to call.the setState method which internally calls build method again where you provide the boolean variable whose status will thereby show and hide view which you intend to do.

Comment: can you show me the code please